# Not showing Validation Errors on Login Page

Tags: django

I am using `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView` for Login page. I cannot display the Validation errors when there is incorrect password or username not found.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.shortcuts import reverse

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
        template_name = 'login.html'

        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('home')
```

login.html

```
    <form method="POST">
         {{ csrf_token }}
         {{ form.username }}
         {{ form.password }}
         <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: try `{{form.errors}}` somewhere in your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes perfect sense, since you do not render the errors. You can render these with:

```
<form method="POST">
  {{ csrf_token }}
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}

  {{ form.username.errors }}
  {{ form.username }}

  {{ form.password.errors }}
  {{ form.password }}
</form>
```

But it might be simpler, to just render the form itself:

```
<form method="POST">
  {{ csrf_token }}
  {{ form }}
</form>
```

For more information, see the [*rendering form error messages* section in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages).

Comment: Yes. I have added non_field_errors and now they are showing and working fine. i didnt use complete form in 1 line because i placed each form field in a different divs and classes

Comment: @MaharshiBingumalla: that is indeed a valid reason. But then you will need to render the `form.field_name.errors` yourself :).